# Linq with array

Tags: linq, arrays, join

```
Dim Cozinhas as string = "1, 2, 3"
Dim FiltroCozinha() As String = Cozinhas.Split(",")

Dim Empresas = (From E In lstEmpresas _
                Group Join CE In lstCozinhasEmpresas On CE.EmpresaID Equals E.EmpresaID Into CEJ = Group From CE In CEJ.DefaultIfEmpty() _
                Group Join FC In lstFiltroCozinha On FC Equals CE.CozinhaID Into FCJ = Group From FC In FCJ.DefaultIfEmpty() _
                Select New With {E.Nome} _
               ).Distinct.ToList
```

Throws exception "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."... but if I remove

```
                Group Join FC In lstFiltroCozinha On FC Equals CE.CozinhaID Into FCJ = Group From FC In FCJ.DefaultIfEmpty() _
```

It works. How do I do left join with the array "FiltroCozinha"?

Comment: http://www.developer.com/db/article.php/3739391/Implementing-a-Left-Join-with-LINQ.htm

Answer (score 1):

I think you are declaring and utilizing the same variable in the same line

`Dim Empresas = (From E In Empresas _`

Comment: Sorry, I simplified the code... consider other name to the object.

...
Dim Empresas = (From E In New BO.Empresa().Select() _
...

The problem continues!

Comment: So are you sure that `lstEmpresas` is not `Nothing`?